# odoo base64 image not working on website for custom module

Tags: base64, odoo, odoo-website

I am creating a custom module. Where in the backend user will be able to upload background image of a section. I have a binary field in the backend for that.

But for some reason the image is not showing. Here is the line of qweb code I am using -

```
<div id="comments1" class="parallax-section"  t-att-style="'background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,'+res_company.website_logo_img+');'">
```

This loads the data in binary format incompatible way.

Following is the screenshot when I first load the webpage and image not shows-
[Google developer Tools inspect element view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmmcD.png)

Following is the screenshot when I just take than line in editable mode and hit enter. The image shows nice and clear:
[Google developer Tools inspect element view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKLfM.png)

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Looks like there might be a space at the end. Developer tools could be fixing this for you. Try using `t-att-style="'background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,{});'.format (res_company.website_logo_img)"`

Comment: Yes, there were sevaral spaces in the binary code. I created an onchange method where binary codes got saved in a char field and when I displayed it with base64 it worked perfectly.
I will try yours too, if it works it will be more efficient. Thanks.

Comment: @PhillipStack your solution didn't work. I used your method to another page and the space still remains.

Comment: t-att-style="'background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,{});'.format (res_company.website_logo_img.replace(' ',''))"

Comment: Maybe try replacing spaces. I commented above. I have not seen this before.